# How to Add 'Data List' in Google Sheet Apps Script that Populates Data from from Google Sheet with Bootstrap and HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, bootstrap-modal, datalist

First of all apologies if this is a silly question as I am a total newbie to coding and programming.

I am trying to create a CRM Webapp using Google Apps Script for my company that stores all of its data in Google Sheet. The work is still in progress.

This CRM Webapp will basically have a Home Tab (to Search and Edit Data), Sales Tab (to enter Sales Entry), Purchase Tab, (to enter Purchase Entry) and Contact Tab (to add Contact Details).

The idea is that a user will first add the contact details of a New Customer/Supplier in the Contact Tab, and this data will be stored in the Google Sheet.

Now to make a Sales or a Purchase Entry, the user will have to now First select the already entered Contact (Only Name, Phone Number and Email Id will be visible) within the respective Tab.

For this I am trying to add a Data List from Bootstrap which will help the user to search and select the already stored Contact Details, and the depending contact fields need to fill automatically based on the Selected Name/Email/Phone.

I tired a lot of methods and referred several posts, but I am not able to populate the Search data from within Google Sheet. I tried using the Dropdown Logic, but even that did not work.

Following is my code. I am pasting only the parts that will look relevant to you guys as the entire thing is very unorganized. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Loadform.gs:

```
function loadForm() {
  
const htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("uform");
const html = htmlServ.evaluate();
html.setWidth(850).setHeight(600);
const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

ui.showModalDialog(html, "VKSPCPL CRM");

}

function createMenu_(){

const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
const menu = ui.createMenu("CRM");
menu.addItem("Open APP", "loadForm");
menu.addToUi(); 

}

function onOpen(){

createMenu_();

}
```

Functions.gs:

```
//Sales Functions---------------------------

function salesEntry(rowDataSales) {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sales Contact Details");
const currentDate = new Date();

const uniqueIDs = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
var maxNum = 0;
uniqueIDs.forEach(r => {
  maxNum = r[0] > maxNum ? r[0] : maxNum
});
var caseNo = maxNum + 1;

ws.appendRow([
  caseNo,
  rowDataSales.inputSalesCxName,
  "Sales",
  rowDataSales.inputSalesCaseOwner,
  currentDate,
  rowDataSales.inputSalesCoName,
  rowDataSales.inputSalesEmail,
  rowDataSales.inputSalesPhone,
  rowDataSales.inputSalesGST,
  rowDataSales.inputSalesCoAdd,
  rowDataSales.inputSalesState]);

  return true;
 
}

function getSalesCaseOwnerDropdown(){

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("CaseOwners");
return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();

}

function salesStateList(){

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("States");
return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();

}

function salesContactName(){

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Contact Details");
return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();

}

    
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Contact Functions--------------------------------------------------------------------------

function getContactDropdown(){

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Customer Type");
return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 2).getValues();

}

function contactEntry(rowDataContact) {

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Contact Details");
const currentDate = new Date();

ws.appendRow([
  rowDataContact.inputContactName,
  rowDataContact.inputContactCoName,
  rowDataContact.inputContactPhone,
  rowDataContact.inputContactEmail,
  rowDataContact.inputContactGST,
  rowDataContact.inputContactCoAdd,
  rowDataContact.inputContactState,
  rowDataContact.inputContactCategory,
  rowDataContact.inputContactType,
  currentDate]);

  return true;
 
}

function contactStateList(){

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("States");
return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();

}
```

uform.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="sales-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#sales" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="sales" aria-selected="false">Sales</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="purchase-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#purchase" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="purchase" aria-selected="false">Purchase</button>
  </li>
   <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact Details</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sales" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="sales-tab">
    
    <br><h3 class="display-6">New Sales Case</h3>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" id="inputSales-CaseOwner">
   
    </select>
    </div>

    <br><h5>Contact Details</h5>

    <form class="row g-3">
       <div class="col-md-4">
      <label for="exampleDataList" class="form-label">Datalist example</label>
      <input class="form-control" list="datalistOptions" id="exampleDataList" placeholder="Type to search...">
      <datalist id="inputSales-CxName">
    
      </datalist>

    ...
    ...
    ...
    
    <script>
    //JS Script Here
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please let me know if you guys need some more scripts or details. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the relationship between `Loadform.gs` and `Functions.gs` and `uform.html`. So I cannot understand about `I tired a lot of methods and referred several posts, but I am not able to populate the Search data from within Google Sheet. I tried using the Dropdown Logic, but even that did not work.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike hi, the loadform.gs has been created to deploy the Userform as a Modal Window. Functions.gs contains all the functions that run at the backend and uform.gs has all the front end html script.

My Goal is to have a searchable dropdown in the 'Sales Tab', that will allow any user to search through the Contacts (captured in the sheet "Contact Details" through the 'Contacts Tab").

The Contacts recorded will have several parameters : Name, Number, Email ID, etc. (and these are recorded in separate columns). (1/n)

Comment: @Tanaike I wish that the user can search for the desired Contact from the 1st Searchable Dropdown in the Sales Tab by entering any of the above mentioned parameters, but only the 'Contact Name' should appear in the said field in the userform. And based on this selection, the rest of the fields (Phone, Email, Company Name) should populate automatically in separate disabled dropdown.

Apologies for the earlier confusion. I hope I was able to explain my problem. (2/2)

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your `Functions.gs`, it seems that the functions of `Functions.gs` are not used at `Loadform.gs` and `uform.html`. `uform.html` is the independent from other files? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, functions.gs is connected with uform.gs. Loadform.gs is independent. If you wish, I could dm you the entire code for better understanding. I did not post it here as it is very unorganized and will look messy

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I would like to try to understand about your question. When I could correctly understand about it and find the solution, I would like to answer it. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Comment: @Tanaike apologies for the explanation. Can you please check this webapp that i have deployed using the script, i hope this will clear things out. Or if needed i can share the google sheet with you 

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwEwD1Z60hOLWo9IQwp38PYEhYpzlmmrbhoXp_3P1KZBqBUZ2LnG1rWxRizlVG-JyVP/exec

Comment: Thank you for your additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From your question I understood that you want a search to be performed that if it matches one of the names you already have stored in your sheet then the [select HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) element options should get populated with the information corresponding to that name and should get disabled.

In order to do so firstly I followed [this detailed and well explained example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms) from Apps Script guides on how to deal with forms and pass form input information to your `code.gs` file. Then, once I checked the input data against the Spreadsheet column `A` that I obtained using [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) I returned the matching data in the selected row corresponding to the inputed name. Finally I simply used [innerHtml](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) and [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to modify the select fields.

I have built a simple and abstracted example on how to achieve what you were aiming for so that other users with similar doubts can learn from it. Please adapt your code to include this example. Below I have inserted images of how the sheet data is structured and of the web app working:

[image]

[image]

The code has self-explanatory comments but if you have any doubts please feel free to ask them:

HTML file, Code file

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');

  return template.evaluate().setTitle('Web App Window Title');
}

// name is an object like this {name : "your inputed name"}
function getData(name) {

// Get the sheet where you have all your data
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Ifqk1LukwzjeZHc7DulMmoZPl34zbHNnLIzFanFAsqI').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  // Get a list of all your stored names. As getValues returns a 2D array, if 
  // you use flat() it will convert it into a 1D array which is of easier manipullation
  var names = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues().flat();
  
  // variable to store matching name data
  var populateElements;
  
  // if the array of names has the name entered in the input
  if(names.includes(name.name)){
  
    // get the index of the matching name in the names array
    var index = names.indexOf(name.name);
    
    // get an array of corresponding values of the name
    // i.e age and field in this example
    populateElements = sheet.getRange(index+2,2,1,2).getValues().flat();
    // return the array of matching fields for that name
    return populateElements;
  }else{
    // if there was no name match just return whatever you want that is not an array
    return "popcorn"
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!-- STYLES -->
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>
    <script>
      // This function is used so that the form submission 
      // does not refresh the web app
      function preventFormSubmit() {
        var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
        for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
          forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        }
      }
      window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

      // Function that gets the data returned getData if everything worked fine
      function onSuccess(data) {
      
      // data is the array of the elements to be populated.
      // In this example [age, field]
      
      // Select the HTML select elements
        var selectAge = document.getElementById('age');
        var selectField = document.getElementById('field');
      // create the variables that will store the options
        var optionAge;
        var optionField;
        // if data is an array and thus the name searched was successful and 
        // there were matches
        if(data.length){
        // create an option HTML element for each element in the array
          optionAge = "<option value='" + data[0] + " disabled'>" + data[0] + "</option>";
          
          // and set it to the corresponding select element
          selectAge.innerHTML = optionAge;

          optionField = "<option value='" + data[1] + " disabled'>" + data[1] + "</option>";
          selectField.innerHTML = optionField;

        }

      }

      // This function will run when the form is submitted
      // formObject is that data submitted. In this case this is equals to {name:name}
      function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
      
      // set to run getData passing the inputed name and if successful run the function
      // ablove onSuccess
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getData(formObject);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      Select Name
    </h1>

    <!-- On this form submission this will call the function handleFormSubmit -->
    <!-- and it will pass the input value -->
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
      <input name="name" type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    
    <!-- The select inputs that will be modified on the name search -->
    <select name="age" id="age">
      <option value="Selection 1">Selection 1</option>
      <option value="Selection 2">Selection 2</option>
    </select>

    <select name="field" id="field">
      <option value="Selection 1">Selection 1</option>
      <option value="Selection 2">Selection 2</option>
    </select>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your reply. I got it to working for the most part. I was wondering if there is a way to add a searchable dropdown instead of the input field. I am not finding a way to do so on bootstrap 4. here is my actual problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66490112/adding-bootstrap-4-searchable-dropdown-in-google-apps-script

Comment: Glad it solved your question ! :D There are no searchable ```select``` elements as such on HTML or Bootstrap but you could use a [datalist](w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) instead.

Comment: hi I did manage to add a searchable dropdown using <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">, but it has now stopped populating the options from the data in the google sheet. not sure what needs to be done here