# Adding Bootstrap 4 Searchable Dropdown in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, bootstrap-4, dropdown, bootstrap-select

So I have been trying to use Bootstrap-select to add a search feature in my dropdown menu for Google Apps Script.

I tried following [this guide](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/), and added the cdn and js available [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/), but I cant seem to get it working in my Google Apps Script Webapp. All I am getting is a dropdown with no option to serach.

Below is my code, can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

uform.html:

```
        <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
      </head>
      <body>
      
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="sales-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#sales" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="sales" aria-selected="false">Sales</button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="purchase-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#purchase" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="purchase" aria-selected="false">Purchase</button>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact Details</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">1</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sales" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="sales-tab">
        
        <br><h3 class="display-6">New Sales Case</h3>
    
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" id="inputSales-CaseOwner">
       
        </select>
        </div>
    
        <br><h5>Contact Details</h5>
    
        <form class="row g-3">
           <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="inputSales-CxName" class="form-label">Search with Phone Number</label>
            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" aria-label="Default select example" id="inputSales-CxName">
          
            </select>
           </div>

 </form>
       <br><div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-button-contact">Save</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
    
    
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
   <script>
function afterFormLoadsSalesCaseOwner(){

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSalesDropdownReturned).getSalesCaseOwnerDropdown();

    }

    function afterSalesDropdownReturned(arrayOfArrays){
      var item = document.getElementById("inputSales-CaseOwner");

      arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(r){
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.textContent = r[0];
        item.appendChild(option);

      });


    }
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",afterFormLoadsSalesCaseOwner);
</script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

functions.gs:

```
function getSalesCaseOwnerDropdown(){

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("CaseOwners");
return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();

}
```

What my Result Looks Like:

[Screenshot from Webapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKqh0.png)
I need a search box in this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You must to add stylesheet  into your head after bootstrap stylesheets.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
```

and add script into body

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="sales-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#sales" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="sales" aria-selected="false">Sales</button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="purchase-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#purchase" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="purchase" aria-selected="false">Purchase</button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact Details</button>
      </li>
    </ul>


    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">1</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sales" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="sales-tab">

        <br>
        <h3 class="display-6">New Sales Case</h3>

        <div class="col-md-4">
          <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" id="inputSales-CaseOwner">

          </select>
        </div>

        <br>
        <h5>Contact Details</h5>

        <form class="row g-3">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="inputSales-CxName" class="form-label">Search with Phone Number</label>
            <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" aria-label="Default select example" id="inputSales-CxName">

            </select>
          </div>

        </form>
        <br>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-button-contact">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
  <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.6.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-KsvD1yqQ1/1+IA7gi3P0tyJcT3vR+NdBTt13hSJ2lnve8agRGXTTyNaBYmCR/Nwi" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-nsg8ua9HAw1y0W1btsyWgBklPnCUAFLuTMS2G72MMONqmOymq585AcH49TLBQObG" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


  <script>
    function getSalesCaseOwnerDropdown() {

      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      const ws = ss.getSheetByName("CaseOwners");
      return ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues();

    }
  </script>

  <script>
    function afterSalesDropdownReturned(arrayOfArrays) {
      var item = document.getElementById("inputSales-CaseOwner");

      arrayOfArrays.forEach(function(r) {
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.textContent = r[0];
        item.appendChild(option);

      });


    }

    function afterFormLoadsSalesCaseOwner() {

      //google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSalesDropdownReturned).getSalesCaseOwnerDropdown();

    }


    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", afterFormLoadsSalesCaseOwner);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Continue to pay attention to the scripts order**

Comment: hi, thank you for your response. I was able to add the search bar in my dropdown, but it has now stopped populating the options that it used to previously populate from the data in the google spreadsheet. can you please help me with fixing that?

Comment: @AdityaBajaj you must uncomment `google.script.run...` in `afterFormLoadsSalesCaseOwner()`

Comment: hey, if I remove that, how will the dropdown fetch data from my js function? Sorry for bothering, but I am new to this, and its not working

Comment: Don't delete, just uncomment,

Comment: Your drop-down working searchable just need data, you must pass data to that